# MSCS LaTeX style won't compile

Tags: documentclass

I am trying to prepare a manuscript to submit to MSCS. I have downloaded the [MSCS LaTeX style package](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-file-manager/file/5dd500bb4a8612ad0a932d3a)  (as suggested at the [author instructions page](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/mathematical-structures-in-computer-science/information/instructions-contributors)). However, I cannot compile even the MSCguide.tex  file included in the package.

The first error that I receive is about the `mtsy` font:

```
[...]
kpathsea: Running mktextfm mtsy
mktextfm: Running mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; ; nonstopmode; input mtsy
This is METAFONT, Version 2.7182818 (TeX Live 2020/Arch Linux) (preloaded base=mf)


kpathsea: Running mktexmf mtsy
! I can't find file `mtsy'.
<*> ...:=ljfour; mag:=1; ; nonstopmode; input mtsy

Please type another input file name
! Emergency stop.
<*> ...:=ljfour; mag:=1; ; nonstopmode; input mtsy

Transcript written on mfput.log.
grep: mtsy.log: No such file or directory
mktextfm: `mf-nowin -progname=mf \mode:=ljfour; mag:=1; ; nonstopmode; input mtsy' failed to make mtsy.tfm.
kpathsea: Appending font creation commands to missfont.log.

! Font \mtsyfont=mtsy at 5.35pt not loadable: Metric (TFM) file not found.
l.4166 \font\mtsyfont = mtsy at 5.35pt

?
```

I have found a mtsy.tfm file online, so I placed it in the same folder, and now I receive the following error message:

```
[...]
(./MSCguide.aux) (/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ot1ptm.fd)
(/usr/share/texmf-dist/tex/context/base/mkii/supp-pdf.mkii
[LoadingMPStoPDFconverter(version2006.09.02).]
! Missing number, treated as zero.
<to be read again>
                   \relax
l.136 ...csname newcount\endcsname \scratchcounter

?
```

I cannot make sense of these errors, since I am compiling the MSCguide.tex included in the package.

Here is the output of `pdflatex --version:`

```
pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020/Arch Linux)
kpathsea version 6.3.2
Compiled with libpng 1.6.37; using libpng 1.6.37
Compiled with zlib 1.2.11; using zlib 1.2.11
Compiled with poppler version 20.08.0
```

Comment: there is no mtsy.tfm in the standard distributions so it's not surprising it fails, it is surprising that they use it in an author guide but that's not a technical question that can be answered.

Comment: This style is a mess. I just tried a minimal example with `\documentclass{msc}` followed by `\begin{document} Nothing \end{document}` and still have errors. Can't believe that a good journal as MSCS from a good university as Cambridge have such a sloppy "instruction to authors".

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Oh, you're right. Sorry for the confusion, I have deleted the corresponding comment.

Comment: the class fails (and even more drastically with a new latex) as it redefines \@pushfilename in a incompatible way. Beside this it shouldn't load etex, and not use local fonts, and it should check its various redefinition of internal commands like \@outputpage. Write to the authors.